# A function that returns the result but paste it special as value on the same cell where the function was written?

Tags: excel, vba

How I can right a function that returns the result in the same cell but paste it special as value on the same cell where the function was written?

for example cell B2 I wrote the function =txtGetId(A2) 
so now B2 has returned for example "T1011" now I want that result to be paste special as a value in B2 :)

This is my function, which basically loop through all raws and automatically assign a new ID.

```
Function txtGetID(CellRef As String) As String
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim rw As Range
Dim numID As String
Dim RowCount As Integer
Dim txtID As String
Dim txtcellID As String
Dim ResID As String
Dim fflag As Integer
Dim FResID As String
Dim txtCellValue As String
RowCount = 0
Set sh = ActiveSheet
ResID = sh.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value
fflag = 1
numID = "00"

Do While fflag = 1
    fflag = 0
    numID = Right("00" & LTrim(Str((Val(numID) + 1))), 2)

    For Each rw In sh.Rows
        If sh.Cells(rw.Row, 1).Value = "" Then
            Exit For
        End If

        txtCellValue = sh.Cells(rw.Row, 1).Value

        If ResID & numID = txtCellValue Then
            fflag = 1
            Exit For
        End If

        'txtcellID = sh.Cells(rw.Row, 1).Value

        If sh.Cells(rw.Row, 1).Value = "" Then
            Exit For
        End If

    Next rw
        For Each rw In sh.Rows
        If fflag = 1 Then
            Exit For
        End If


        txtCellValue = sh.Cells(rw.Row, 5).Value

        If ResID & numID = txtCellValue Then
            fflag = 1
            Exit For
        End If

        'txtcellID = sh.Cells(rw.Row, 3).Value

        If sh.Cells(rw.Row, 5).Value = "" Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next rw

Loop
FResID = ResID & numID
txtGetID = FResID
End Function
```

writing anything before the "End of Function" statement will just be useless because the function will return with the result at the end. I tried to use this

```
ActiveCell.Activate
ActiveCell.Select
activecell.Value=FResID
```

but it did nothing at all.

Comment: This is not a free code service. Post your attempt so we can help you with it.

Comment: `Range("A1").value2 = Range("A1").value2` will replace a formula by its value

Comment: @Dean you are right! and what you said was not my intention! anyway I added more details as you suggested

Answer (score 0):

What you could try (simplified):

1) Create your function, e.g.:

```
Public ADRS As String

Option Explicit

Function Test(RNG As Range) As String

ADRS = ActiveCell.Address
Test = RNG.Value

End Function
```

2) When entered, the function will trigger the worksheet calculate event, so under the specific worksheet write, e.g.:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Range(ADRS).Value = Range(ADRS).Value

End Sub
```

You could also put it under `ThisWorkbook` like so:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)

Range(ADRS).Value = Range(ADRS).Value

End Sub
```